# Javascript removes the decimals when adding numbers together

Tags: javascript, integer, decimal, rounding

I have this script that adds the 4 numbers together but JS doesn't take into account the original decimal places.

// Initial input form

```
<form class="weight_form" data-ajax="false" method="post">
<input type="text" class="input_save" placeholder="save as.."/>
<input type="text" id="lf" placeholder="enter LF lbs" value="" onkeyup="myFunction()"/>
<input type="text" id="rf" placeholder="enter RF lbs" value="" onkeyup="myFunction()"/>
<input type="text" id="lr" placeholder="enter LR lbs" value="" onkeyup="myFunction()"/>
<input type="text" id="rr" placeholder="enter RR lbs" value="" onkeyup="myFunction()"/>
<input type="submit" id="sub_save" value="save"/>
```

// Section to display results

```
<div id="bottom_section">
    <input type="text" id="total"  value=""/>
    <input type="text" id="cross"  value=""/>
    <input type="text" id="ls"  value=""/>
    <input type="text" id="bite"  value=""/>    
</div>
```

// JS script to perform action on the fly

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
var lf = document.getElementById("lf");
var rf = document.getElementById("rf");
var lr = document.getElementById("lr");
var rr = document.getElementById("rr");

var lf = parseInt(lf.value);
var rf = parseInt(rf.value);
var lr = parseInt(lr.value);
var rr = parseInt(rr.value);

  var lf_1 = lf*1;
  var rf_1 = rf*1;
  var lr_1 = lr*1;
  var rr_1 = rr*1;

  var total = lf_1 + rf_1 + lr_1 + rr_1;
  var cross = rf_1 + lr_1 / total;
  var ls = lf_1 + lr_1 / total;
  var bite = lr_1 - rr_1;


$('#total').val(total);
$('#cross').val(Math.round(cross));
$('#ls').val(Math.round(ls));
$('#bite').val(bite);
};
</script>
```

If I enter say 20.5 for each input in the "weight_form" (lf, rf, lr, rr) the total is 80 instead of 82. Why does it seem to always round down the value?

Comment: you take `parseInt` instead of `parseFloat`. `parseInt` returns an integer number.

Comment: yep thats it dang.. Thanks mate add it as an answer so I can except it..

Comment: Blame it on the wrong method used...not the language. When in doubt research the methods used first

Comment: `parseInt` just truncates numbers after point

Comment: yep definitely not the languages fault I need to llok in the mirror on this one

Comment: @RyanD could I suggest that you use better naming conventions with your variables? If I were code reviewing this for you, that is one of the first comments I would make

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, I usually do but this is a personal script only I will ever use and these terms are the easiest for me to remember.. Usually I go over board like var = this_will_make_the_button_do_something lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To handle **floats** in your **form**, use [**`parseFloat`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) instead of [**`parseInt`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt), when parsing your values from the `input` elements.

Since you're using **jQuery**, you can simplify `myFunction` by selecting your fields and parse their values in one line:

```
var lf = parseFloat($("#lf").val());
var rf = parseFloat($("#rf").val());
var lr = parseFloat($("#lr").val());
var rr = parseFloat($("#rr").val());
```

**Example:**

```js
function myFunction() {
  var lf = parseFloat($("#lf").val());
  var rf = parseFloat($("#rf").val());
  var lr = parseFloat($("#lr").val());
  var rr = parseFloat($("#rr").val());

  var lf_1 = lf * 1;
  var rf_1 = rf * 1;
  var lr_1 = lr * 1;
  var rr_1 = rr * 1;

  var total = lf_1 + rf_1 + lr_1 + rr_1;
  var cross = rf_1 + lr_1 / total;
  var ls = lf_1 + lr_1 / total;
  var bite = lr_1 - rr_1;

  $('#total').val(total);
  $('#cross').val(Math.round(cross));
  $('#ls').val(Math.round(ls));
  $('#bite').val(bite);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="weight_form" data-ajax="false" method="post">
  <input type="text" class="input_save" placeholder="save as.." />
  <input type="text" id="lf" placeholder="enter LF lbs" value="" onkeyup="myFunction()" />
  <input type="text" id="rf" placeholder="enter RF lbs" value="" onkeyup="myFunction()" />
  <input type="text" id="lr" placeholder="enter LR lbs" value="" onkeyup="myFunction()" />
  <input type="text" id="rr" placeholder="enter RR lbs" value="" onkeyup="myFunction()" />
  <input type="submit" id="sub_save" value="save" />
  <div id="bottom_section">
    <input type="text" id="total" value="" />
    <input type="text" id="cross" value="" />
    <input type="text" id="ls" value="" />
    <input type="text" id="bite" value="" />
  </div>
</form>
```